# Git: How to rebase one remote off another remote

Tags: git, rebase

I have two remote git branches (call them "RemoteA" and "RemoteB").

"RemoteB" was branched off of "RemoteA" some time in the past. After that point many commits have been applied to both branches but I now want "RemoteB" to pick up all of the commits in "RemoteA".

```
A-B-C-D-E  (RemoteA)
 \
  F-G-H-I  (RemoteB)
```

One idea I had was to attempt to rebase "RemoteB" based off of the latest tag in "RemoteA", but I've seen some community posts advising against that. Is this possible (any sample commands would be appreciated) and if so is it something I should even attempt?

```
A-B-C-D-E  (RemoteA)
         \
          F-G-H-I  (RemoteB)
```

Another idea was to create a new branch off of "RemoteA", call it "RemoteC" and manually cherry pick changes from "RemoteB" onto it. What are the best practices for this type of situation?

Comment: A "remote" branch is your (local) git remembering what it got from someone else's (remote) git.  You can't change what they did, you can only change things when *you* do them.  So although it's possible via low level commands to fool your git into thinking they rebased their remote and you then picked that up, that's not a good idea, because they didn't, *you* did it.  So don't try to rebase a remote.  Rebase locally, then convince the other guy (the remote) to take your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are remote branches (and assuming that you are not working in isolation), it is a very bad idea to rebase one onto the other.

This is because rebasing "B" onto "A" will recreate the entire history of "B".  Anybody else who will retrieve the remote "B" will now have to deal with that (usually that means they are seeing conflicting changes).  You will be making live miserable for your collaborators.

To pick up the changes from "A" and incorporate them into "B", checkout your local version of "B", and merge "A" into it.  Then push the updated "B" to the remote repository.

As a general rule: do not rebase branches that are already in a remote repository, unless you're the only person working with that remote.

Comment: What I didn't like about the merging "A" onto "B" was that it seemed like that would give me a fairly unclean looking history. That's why I was thinking of making branchC. Is there anyway, with the merge, to have a fairly clean looking history?

Comment: If you want to have a "linear history" (I assume that's what you mean by "clean looking"), then you have to make an entirely new branch, where you rebase "B" onto "A" (or you rewrite remote "A", but then your collaborators need to be aware of that).  In either case, rebasing will effectively *destroy* an important aspect of history information - keep that in mind when you are going for the "clean look".

Comment: In short: your original idea of making a new branch "C" for the rebasing is correct, and will work in practice.  However, what are you doing with branches "A" and "B" after that?  Discard them?  That seems like an unnecessary disruption to the work flow.

Comment: Thanks for the info Sigi. I think I will checkout/create a local Branch"C" off of Branch"B", rebase Branch"C" off of Branch"A", and then push Branch"C" up to the server as a remote. Branch"A" would then continue to exist and be actively developed on.  Branch"B" would be somewhat inactive which I think should be fine. This process should only be happening on a rare occasion so I don't mind having misc branches hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the best practices for this type of situation?

That mainly depends on whether there is a chance that other people already have seen the commits in both branches.

- If one branch—say, `RemoteB`—is on your local machine and has never been pushed to a public repository, you can safely rebase it on top of the other branch:

  ```
  git checkout RemoteB
  git rebase RemoteA
  ```
- Otherwise, the usual method is to merge one branch into the other:

  ```
  git checkout RemoteB
  git merge RemoteA
  ```